# how to Create Custom Panorama Tiles for Creating of custom Street view

Tags: google-street-view, panoramas

i need some advise on how do i create Creating Custom Panorama Tiles for creating the custom street view

i am able to create equirectange panorama of 10000x5000  but i saw that i need to slice them into tiles.

i am also confuse over how should i label them.

[return 'images/panoReception1024-' + zoom + '-' + tileX + '-' +tileY +'.jpg']

this is the example i got from the google street view document help.

but , assume i have a 3000x1500, and i set the tile size to 512, i need to create 12X6? am i right?

then how do i create the different zoom level?

1. Zoom 0 is the original file?
2. Zoom 1/2/3/4, how do i create the tiles for them and how do i label them?

hope can get some advise

thank u for reading and helping

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've found an answer, yet.

Essentially, you have to break the panorama pic into 8 columns and 4 rows.

So the top row from left to right would be: 
panoReception-0-0.jpg, panoReception-1-0.jpg,...,panoReception-8-0.jpg

The second row from left to right would be: 
panoReception-0-1.jpg, panoReception-1-1.jpg,...,panoReception-8-1.jpg

I found full instructions on this website:
http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/custom_streetview/3.html

Answer (score 1):

- Ideally the tiles should be of dimensions: 256 x 256 pixels
- Resize your panoramic to this size: 8192 x 4096 pixels
- The images get loaded as a pyramid, at various zoom levels
- The zoom levels are 0,1,2,3,4. Optionally you may also use a level 5.

  ```
    
      var heightY = Math.pow(2, zoom - 1);
      var widthX = 2 * heightY;
  ```
- The above JavaScript code shows the image dimensions at various pyramid (zoom) levels
- Loop your code to slice images. Following is your counter for x and y axis.

  ```
    
      var xCount = widthX / 256;
      var yCount = heightY / 256;
  ```
- The tile format is **pano_z_x_y.jpeg**, where z is zoom. x is horizontal count, and y is vertical count for the required tile image
- At zoom 0, you get single image pano_0_0_0.jpeg
- At zoom 1, you get two images pano_1_0_0.jpeg & pano_1_1_0.jpeg
- At zoom 2, you get 8 images
- At zoom 3, you get 32 images
- At zoom 4, you get 128 images

Pass over these images to your JavaScript function as below:

```
function getCustomPanoramaTileUrl(pano, zoom, tileX, tileY) 
{
      return 'pano' + '_' + zoom + '_' + tileX + '_' + tileY + '.jpeg';
}
```