# Google Maps Javascript API v3 - Ricoh Theta & Custom Street View Panorama

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, photosphere

I need your help, and I will be short.

I've got a Ricoh Theta camera (360 degrees camera). Now I want to add a Custom Street View Panorama to my website. However, the API transforms all the images uploaded from Ricoh Theta incorrectly.
The ratio of the images is **3584 x 1792**

I've figured out that different browsers display my images differently. Firefox and IE do a relatively good job, but it's still not what Google's panoramas look like.

**UPDATE:**
This is what I've done so far. I was strictly following the Google's examples from the documentation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>16 Dempsey Crescent</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true">
    </script>
<script>
var panorama;

// The panorama that will be used as the entry point to the custom
// panorama set.
var entryPanoId = null;

function initialize() {
  // The latlng of the entry point to the Google office on the road.
  var dempseyCres = new google.maps.LatLng(43.753859,-79.374082);

  // Set up the map and enable the Street View control.
  var mapOptions = {
    center: dempseyCres,
    zoom: 16
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  panorama = map.getStreetView();
  // Set up Street View and initially set it visible. Register the
  // custom panorama provider function.
  var panoOptions = {
    position: dempseyCres,
    visible: true,
    panoProvider: getCustomPanorama
  };
  panorama.setOptions(panoOptions);

  // Create a StreetViewService object.
  var streetviewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

  // Compute the nearest panorama to the Google Sydney office
  // using the service and store that pano ID.
  var radius = 50;
  streetviewService.getPanoramaByLocation(dempseyCres, radius,
      function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
      // We'll monitor the links_changed event to check if the current
      // pano is either a custom pano or our entry pano.
      google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'links_changed',
        function() {
          createCustomLinks(result.location.pano);
        });
    }
  });
}

function getCustomPanoramaTileUrl(pano, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
  // Return a pano image given the panoID.
  /*return 'images/panoReception1024-' + zoom + '-' + tileX + '-' + tileY +
      '.jpg';*/
      return 'images/R0010029.JPG';

}

function getCustomPanorama(pano) {
  switch (pano) {
    case 'room-1':
      return {
        location: {
          pano: 'room-1',
          description: '16 Dempsey Crescent',
          latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(43.753859,-79.374082)
        },
        links: [],
        // The text for the copyright control.
        copyright: 'Imagery (c) 2010 Google',
        // The definition of the tiles for this panorama.
        tiles: {
          tileSize: new google.maps.Size(1700, 850),
          worldSize: new google.maps.Size(3584, 1792),
          // The heading at the origin of the panorama tile set.
          centerHeading: 105,
          getTileUrl: getCustomPanoramaTileUrl
        }
      };
      break;
    default:
      return null;
  }
}

function createCustomLinks(entryPanoId) {
  var links = panorama.getLinks();
  var panoId = panorama.getPano();

  switch (panoId) {
    case entryPanoId:
      // Adding a link in the view from the entrance of the building to
      // reception.
      links.push({
        heading: 340,
        description: 'Enter The House',
        pano: 'room-1'
      });
      break;
    case 'room-1':
      // Adding a link in the view from the entrance of the office
      // with an arrow pointing at 100 degrees, with a text of 'Exit'
      // and loading the street entrance of the building pano on click.
      links.push({
        heading: 110,
        description: 'Back to the Street',
        pano: entryPanoId
      });
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would really appreciate, if you helped me solving this issue.

Comment: Can you add the sample code of what you have done so far so we can help you debug it?

Comment: @Kmeixner Thank you for replying! 
I have updated my post. I would also gladly add pictures, but, unfortunately, my rep is  too low.

Comment: Maybe your panorama variable is wrong. try this   `var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById('map-canvas'), panoOptions);`

Comment: You will need to generate tiles from your main panoramic image, and then use the api to load them, Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459645/how-to-create-custom-panorama-tiles-for-creating-of-custom-street-view/41633282#41633282

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to set your tile options object so that world and tile size are equal?  It seems you don't have tiles so much as one big panorama.

```
tiles: {
      tileSize: new google.maps.Size(3584, 1792),
      worldSize: new google.maps.Size(3584, 1792),
      // The heading at the origin of the panorama tile set.
      centerHeading: 105,
      getTileUrl: getCustomPanoramaTileUrl
    }
```